# Lipschitz Smoothness and Nesterov's Accelerated Gradient Descend

Tags: lipschitz-functions, gradient-descent

I am reading about [Nesterov's Accelerated Gradient Descend](https://blogs.princeton.edu/imabandit/2013/04/01/acceleratedgradientdescent/), and trying to apply it to my application (Computerised Tomography), which essentially means I am solving a linear problem of the form

$$
\hat{x}=\underset{x}{\text{argmin}}\left\{ \lVert Ax-b\rVert^2\right\}
$$

Regardless of the complexity of the proof, ultimately the algorithm seems fairly easy to implement, as it is just a slight modification from the classic gradient descend with some specific parameter updates. Nesterov's acceleration ends in an update that looks like:

$$
y_{s+1}=x_{x}-\frac{1}{\beta}\nabla f(x_s)\\
x_{s+1}=(1-\gamma_s)y_{s+1}+\gamma_s y_s
$$
 for iteration number $s$ and $\gamma_s=\frac{1-\lambda_s}{\lambda_{s+1}}$, being $\lambda_S=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4{\lambda_{s-1}^2}}}{2}$.

However it relies in the $\beta$-smoothness of the function $f$, and $\beta$ is used in as a parameter.

$f$ is  $ \lVert Ax-b\rVert^2$

What value should I give to $\beta$? How can I know how $\beta$-smooth my function is?

Comment: If you're minimizing $\|Ax-b\|^2$, then isn't $f(x)=\|Ax-b\|^2$ in your case? And $\nabla f(x) = 2 A^T(Ax-b)$.

Comment: As a no-answer to my question: pretty much everyone just uses $\beta=1$ or some similar value. It apparently is not too important what value is given to that variable when doing numerical stuff.

Comment: @littleO the question has been clarified, you're welcome to take a shot at it (my answer wasn't corresponding to the actual question).

Comment: So you want know whether you can choose $\beta=1$ as an upper bound for the $\beta$ that satisfy $\Vert \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \Vert = \Vert 2 A^t A (x-y) \Vert \leq \beta \Vert x-y\Vert \forall x,y$  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient of $f$ is $\nabla f(x) = 2 A^T(Ax-b)$. To use Nesterov's method we need a Lipschitz constant for $\nabla f$ (not $f$). Notice that
\begin{align}
\| \nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y) \| &= 
\|2 A^T A(x-y) \| \\
&\leq 2 \| A^T A \| \|x-y\| \\
&= 2 \| A\|^2 \|x-y\|^2.
\end{align}
So a Lipschitz constant for $\nabla f$ is 
$$
\beta= 2 \|A\|^2.
$$

Comment: So this $\beta = 2\Vert A \Vert^2$ is an upper bound could it be that there might actually be a lower $\beta$ than your suggested one?